# How to let ruby/rails debugger only jump into application codes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When doing Rails development, and shen using `debugger`
it often happens that `step` leads to library code,
is there a way to restrict it only jumping into my application's code?
Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using `step`, use `next`.

From the Rails guide:

> The difference between next and step is that step stops at the next
>   line of code executed, doing just a single step, while next moves to
>   the next line without descending inside methods.

Assuming you set your breakpoint within your application code, `next` will not descend into library code. It will stay "in frame".